# Neutrino path bent by gravity?

Tags: neutrinos, faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Neutrino unaffected by gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/neutrino-unaffected-by-gravity)

Other probably closely related questions here:

[Link Neutrinos unaffected by gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/neutrino-unaffected-by-gravity)
[Link Superluminal Neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/superluminal-neutrinos)

My question is subtly different (I hope).

Gravitational lensing demonstrates that light is bent by massive bodies. If neutrinos and light are bent by the earth's gravity would we be able to measure that? I suppose we would need to take measurements of the difference between traveling into/out of our gravity well and across the gravity well.

A good deal of discussion is going on about the Gran Sasso experiment and one of the points that keeps being mentioned is the time it took for neutrinos to arrive from a supernova explosion.

The light/neutrinos from the supernova are traveling **into** our gravity well and will therefore not be bent by the earth's gravity while the Gran Sasso neutrinos are traveling **across** and will be. What *should* the difference be?

Comment: While this question is more carefully worded, I believe it is a very good match for the first existing question you link to. I mean *"could that be a plausible reason for a neutrino taking a shorter path than light"* goes right to the matter of "bent" versus "straight" paths, no? I'm closing it, but I'll give you a tick up for righting a better title and body.

Comment: I felt this one was different because a) I am assuming neutrinos ARE affected by gravity and b) so is light. Therefore Einstein was right but we've just got the measurements wrong ... we've been using bent light all along. If I change the question to add that, would it no longer be a duplicate?

Comment: Apologies! I have re-read the other question and the answer does cover both points. Neutrinos take exactly the same path as light.