# Can neutrinos orbit galaxy centre like stars do?

Tags: gravity, neutrinos, space

I am layman in particle physics. I saw  [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/are-neutrinos-affected-by-gravity) about gravitation affecting neutrinos. There is link to an article, but it is too difficult for me. Is it known if and where can neutrinos orbit heavy objects, say centre of galaxy, is their trajectory stable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neutrinos have mass and so they are affected by gravity (indeed, even if they were massless, they would still be affected by gravity, just as photons are). However, the mass of a neutrino is very very small, so neutrinos emitted by the the nuclear fusion processes inside stars (and in even more extreme events such as supernovae) have speeds that are very close to the speed of light - they are *relativistic* particles. Because they travel at speeds so close to the speed of light, it is very difficult to directly measure the speed of a neutrino and this is an area of ongoing research - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurements_of_neutrino_speed)

To go into a closed orbit around a galaxy, a star or even a black hole, a neutrino would have to lose energy and slow down. But because they are not affected by the electromagnetic force or the strong nuclear force, neutrinos hardly ever interact with other particles, so a relativistic neutrino is very unlikely to lose enough energy to ever go into a closed orbit.

Comment: MIght be fun (so to speak) to calculate either the required total mass vs. a putative speed such as 0.99c and  distance from center to achieve an elliptical orbit, or to calculate the necessary expansion of the Universe to do the same.

Comment: Considering that light can "fall" into a black hole, so can neutrinos, which actually do have a mass. In the range between falling into the black hole and being on a unbound orbit, there is also a bound orbit. In fact, even for light there is a theoretical orbit around a black hole, called the photon sphere. This orbit is unstable, but for neutrinos, which have a mass, there should be a stable orbit. Moreover, neutrinos created at big bang would be expected to be slowed down significantly. However, we don't have the technology to detect neutrinos slower than extremely near the speed of light.